# Access microphone through java plugin for voice chat

Tags: java, audio, voip, microphone

How to create a java plugin that can directly access the microphone for specific **web application**  in java ?..   **..i don't want to use applet & flash........**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use java and this is web application (UI in browser) - than you have to use applet. I don't know other way. And this applet should be signed with certificate. Also user should accept this certificate to let java sound api access client device.

Or you can create java web start application (JNLP) that will be downloaded and running on client PC. But this will not be a web ui.

Comment: I know to use system resourses like mic for web application we have to use signed applet ........is it possible to create browser plugin in java that can directly interact with mic and our web application get audio stream through that plugin........

Comment: Different browser supports plugins, like firefox. But I am not sure this is java. I think you should have different plugin for every browser you would like to support. Maybe applet is easiest way?

Comment: but applet get installed every time at browser when we want to access mic....but in case of plugin it installed for first time only....can you tell me how to create java plugins for different browsers...

Comment: Yes, but if it is not changed - it is cached. Also there is one benephit from applet: you can update, upload to server and changes will be delivered via internet to clients. No nead to reinstall. Can you do so with plugin? Size of applet - is several kB. Even for dialup internet - it is ok. User accept certificate only once. And you get all working in single application. And I don't know how to create different plugins for different browsers. And I don't want to know it - because there is java applet can deliver this functionality for you. Simpler and faster.